# Basics of c# and string quesion

Tags: c#, string

I am new in programming. What do the question mark and the colon mean below?

```
string str= "PHP Tutorial";
Console.WriteLine((str.Substring(1, 2).Equals("HP") ? str.Remove(1, 2) : str));
```

Comment: This is the very useful conditional expression, see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Answer (score 2):

This is a shorthand for an if-Statement.

The same could also be written like this:

```
string str = "PHP Tutorial";
if(str.Substring(1, 2).Equals("HP")) {
    Console.WriteLine(str.Remove(1, 2));
} else {
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
a = b ? c : d;
```

is shorthand for:

```cs
if (b)
    a = c;
else
    a = d;
```

The C# [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) evaluates the first operand, which must be a Boolean expression, and returns the second operand if it's `true` and the third operand if it's `false`. The second and third operands must be of the same type so that the overall return type of the expression is known.

Answer (score 0):

C# includes a decision-making operator ?: which is called the conditional operator or ternary operator. It is the short form of the `if else` conditions.

```
condition ? statement 1 : statement 2
```

The following example demonstrates the ternary operator:

```
int x = 20, y = 10;

var result = x > y ? "x is greater than y" : "x is less than y";

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

output:

```
x is greater than y
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator